# Как записать большой txt файл, кодируя в base64 по частям?

Tags: c#, base64

У меня есть данные, которые я получаю в виде байт-массивов. Их нужно кодировать в [base64](http://www.herongyang.com/encoding/Base64-Encoding-Algorithm.html) и добавлять в файл в txt-формате таким образом, чтобы в итоге вышло, что как-будто файл был закодирован сразу целиком, а не по частям.

Поясню:
Convert.ToBase64String(...) в сишарп кодирует переданные ему байт массивы в нужный формат. Но мне нужно добиться эффекта, как-будто файл был кодирован и записан целиком, а не по частям.

Код ниже. Есть ошибка, которую не могу отловить. Записываемый по кускам файл не соответствует исходному, хотя все проверил. Я не очень опытен, пока не знаю тонкостей, и если заметите ошибку, сообщите, пожалуйста.

Код проверяет длину полученного массива кратности трём и, соответственно, остатку (2 или 1 или 0). У меня есть байты, которые я добовляю в начало следующего принятого массива и дозаписываю. Еще: как узнать, что был передан в метод последний массив, чтобы его дописать?

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{           
    if ((buffer.Length % 3) != 0)
    {
        if ((buffer.Length % 3) == 1)
        {
            if (twoElements.Count == 0 && oneElement == -1)
            {
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 1);
                File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
                oneElement = buffer[buffer.Length - 1];
            }
            else if (twoElements.Count != 0 && oneElement == -1)
            {
                listBuffer.AddRange(twoElements);
                listBuffer.AddRange(buffer);
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(listBuffer.ToArray(), 0, listBuffer.ToArray().Length);
                File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
                twoElements.Clear();
                listBuffer.Clear();
            }
            else if (twoElements.Count == 0 && oneElement != -1)
            {
                listBuffer.Add((byte)oneElement);
                listBuffer.AddRange(buffer);
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(listBuffer.ToArray(), 0, listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 2);
                File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
                twoElements.Add(listBuffer.ToArray()[listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 2]);
                twoElements.Add(listBuffer.ToArray()[listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 1]);
                oneElement = -1;
                listBuffer.Clear();
            }
        }
        else if ((buffer.Length % 3) == 2)
        {
            if (twoElements.Count == 0 && oneElement == -1)
            {
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 2);
                File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
                twoElements.Add(buffer[buffer.Length - 2]);
                twoElements.Add(buffer[buffer.Length - 1]);
            }
            else if (twoElements.Count != 0 && oneElement == -1)
            {
                listBuffer.AddRange(twoElements);
                listBuffer.AddRange(buffer);
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(listBuffer.ToArray(), 0, listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 1);
                File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
                oneElement = listBuffer.ToArray()[listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 1];
                twoElements.Clear();
                listBuffer.Clear();
            }
            else if (twoElements.Count == 0 && oneElement != -1)
            {
                listBuffer.Add((byte)oneElement);
                listBuffer.AddRange(buffer);
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(listBuffer.ToArray(), 0, listBuffer.ToArray().Length);
                File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
                oneElement = -1;
                listBuffer.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    else if ((buffer.Length % 3) == 0)
    {
        if (twoElements.Count == 0 && oneElement == -1)
        {
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
        }
        else if (twoElements.Count != 0 && oneElement == -1)
        {
            listBuffer.AddRange(twoElements);
            listBuffer.AddRange(buffer);
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(listBuffer.ToArray(), 0, listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 2);
            File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
            twoElements.Insert(0, listBuffer.ToArray()[listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 2]);
            twoElements.Insert(1, listBuffer.ToArray()[listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 1]);
            listBuffer.Clear();
        }
        else if (twoElements.Count == 0 && oneElement != -1)
        {
            listBuffer.Add((byte)oneElement);
            listBuffer.AddRange(buffer);
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(listBuffer.ToArray(), 0, listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 1);
            File.AppendAllText(m_filein, base64String);
            oneElement = listBuffer.ToArray()[listBuffer.ToArray().Length - 1];
            listBuffer.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кодируйте часть массива длины кратной трем, и пишите результат в файл, а остаток (0, 1 или 2 байта) добавляйте к следующему массиву.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Я так и сделал. Есть код. В нем я проверяю длинну кратности 3ём и соответственно остатку(2 или 1 или 0) у меня есть байты, которые я добовляю в начало следующего массива и дозаписываю. Но как узнать, что был передан в метод последний массив, чтобы его дописать.

Comment: @Matvey, глянул в вашу текущую реализацию... Черт ногу сломит, если честно. Может всё таки проще Stream'ами это делать? )

Comment: Я с удовольствием все упрощу стримами!) Как это можно сделать? Данный метод Write() принадлежит стриму Base64EncoderStream, который принимает большой файл по кусочкам в виде массивов. Задача данного метода - это кодировать и записать данные в файл txt в формате base64 как буд-то фаил был передан и закодирован целиком без хранения исходного файла в памяти. Вот задачка))  Спасибо!

Comment: @Matvey, вы смотрели [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486623/17298)? В нем ваша задача решена именно стримами.

Comment: Да, Сергей, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно:

```
using (var base64Stream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(outputName))
{
    base64Stream.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```

Если исходные данные приходят не в виде Stream'а - создаёте наследник от `Stream`, да читаете и/или консолидируете входящие данные внутри него.